# Multiplying a digit of a number with its current position and then add it with the others using recursion

Tags: c++, function, recursion

the point of this exercise is to multiply a digit of a number with its current position and then add it with the others. **Example: 1234 = 1x4 + 2x3 + 3x2 + 4x1** .I did this code successfully using 2 parameters and now i'm trying to do it with 1. My idea was to use - **return num + mult(a/10) * (a%10)** and get the answer, , because from  **return num + mult(a/10)** i get the values 1,2,3,4- *(1 is for mult(1), 2 for mult(12), etc.)* for **num**, but i noticed that this is only correct for **mult(1)** and then the recursion gets wrong values for **mult(12), mult(123), mult(1234).** My idea is to independently multiply the values **from 'num' with a%10** .  Sorry if i can't explain myself that well, but i'm still really new to programming.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int mult(int a){
int num = 1;
if (a==0){
return 1;
}

return ((num + mult(a/10)) * (a%10));

}


int main()
{
int a = 1234;
cout << mult(a);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: i know, tell that to my instructors. But it's not really hard to guess that in 1x4 , **the 4** stands for the position and not the digit..

Answer (score 0):

I find this easier and more logically to do, Hope this helps lad.

```
int k=1;
int a=1234;
int sum=0;
while(a>0){
   sum=sum+k*(a%10);
   a=a/10;
   k++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I know it's much easier and more logically to do, but that was an exercise which my professor gave us and i don't have much of a choice..

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to do it with recursion and only one argument, you may achieve it with two functions. This is not optimal in terms of number of operations performed, though. Also, it's more of a math exercise than a programming one:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int mult1(int a) {
    if(a == 0) return 0;
    return a % 10 + mult1(a / 10);
}
int mult(int a) {
    if(a == 0) return 0;
    return mult1(a) + mult(a / 10);
}
int main() {
    int a = 1234;
    cout << mult(a) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```